# Is $(ω^ω)^ω$ equal to $ω^{(ω^2)}$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I was just wondering if exponentiation rules such as in the title apply to transfinite ordinals... So things like:

> $\omega^\omega \cdot \omega^\omega = \omega^{\omega2}$

Comment: To get a double superscript, try `$\omega^{\omega^2}$`. It works the same for subscripts too.

Comment: `\cdot` will produce $\cdot$, by the way. A very detailed tutorial on MathJax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, and Asaf, I’ve seen that before, I’m just still getting used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\alpha^{\beta}\cdot\alpha^\gamma = \alpha^{\beta+\gamma}$ and $(\alpha^\beta)^\gamma = \alpha^{\beta\cdot \gamma}$ hold generally for ordinals.

Comment: Thanks, and the one in the title, does $\left(\alpha^\alpha\right)^\alpha = a^{a^2}$?

Comment: @L.McDonald Isn't that a case of the second identity I wrote down? (Also you can just use parentheses. The \left and \right are only for if you want them to size to what's in between)

Comment: Right, sorry, I’m tired and can’t read things properly at the moment...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Perhaps it might also be worth mentioning that $\omega$^$\omega$^$2$ is ambiguous in itself without brackets or precedence assumed? If we mean ($\omega$^$\omega$)^$2$, then it is equal to $\omega^{\omega \cdot 2}$. If we mean $\omega$^($\omega$^$2$), then it is equal to $\omega^{\omega^2}$.